# Regex for IP and string

Tags: java, regex

Im using this regex [online test site](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

Here is the regex im using:

```
\{"ip":"(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$","iphone":"admin/ios","dev":\{"action":"CUS","from":"REG","CUSA":"ADVERT"\}\}
```

And im trying to match it to:

```
{"ip":"192.168.50.5","iphone":"admin/ios","dev":{"action":"CUS","from":"REG","CUSA":"ADVERT"}}
```

When i run the test, it doesn't match, I need it to match on the site above for validation reasons.

Comment: The `$` is an end-of-line boundary matcher; but you've got it in the middle of your pattern.

Comment: Just `\{"ip":"(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}","iphone":"admin/ios","dev":\{"action":"CUS","from":"REG","CUSA":"ADVERT"\}\}` is enough. Test at http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/, it is more "interactive".

Comment: I will be glad if anyone will point me in the directions of regex tried my best, but not able to find any good tutorial

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I removed the $ from the middle but had not luck

Comment: Are you sure? Post what does not work for you.

Comment: I need it to match on here http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html but it doesnot

Comment: Thanks for the accept ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different perspective: it seems that it is already pretty hard to come up with a regex that **initially** works for you. What does this tell you about how hard will it be in the future to maintain this regex; and maybe extend it?!

What I am saying is: regexes are a good tool; but sometimes overrated. This looks like a string in JSON format. Wouldn't it be better to just take it as that, and use a garden-variety JSON parser instead of trying to build your own regex?

You see, what will be more robust over time - your self baked regex; or some standard library that millions of people are using?

One place to read about JSON parsers would be this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) here.

Answer (score -2):

This will be enough for your context.

`"ip":"(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)"`

Edit:

Regex is not for structured data processing, most of the time you need a solution that just works. When sample data changed and doesn't match anymore, you update the regex string to match it again.

Since you want to get four numbers inside a quote pair after a key called "ip", this regex will definitely do it.

If you want something else, please provide more context. Thanks!

Comment: The IP is only one part of this code; and you seriously want to read about IP addresses. Your regex is absolutely not sufficient to go hunting for ip addresses. Yes, first reputation is hard to gain; but well - you have to invest  much more time to come up with quality answers!

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term value.
Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what
limitations and assumptions apply.